# Issues with Continuous Integration trigger in TFS 2012

Tags: .net, tfs, continuous-integration, devops

I have multiple solutions and  common references for all my solutions in the source of my TeamProject as below.

```
TestTeamProject
    Source
       SolutionA
       SolutionB
       SolutionC
       References
```

All the solutions uses Referneces and each solution has a separate build definition. Whenever the build is triggered , a custom activity runs that check-ins their own binaries to the References folder( EX : If the Build Definition configured for SOlution A is triggered it copies the output dlls to References folder), since each solution has dependancies on each other.

Now i tried enabling continuous integration trigger on the Build Definition of SolutionA and it is going into a loop and triggering infinite builds.

**Reason** : Since i have References under the source settings of the Build Definition of Solution A , when ever the build is completed and the references are checked in by my activity, it is again triggering CI build

**Is there any way i could restrict this behaviour by still enabling the CI trigger feature? Is there any extension that could be used to use filters for source control paths while setting up CI builds?**

Answer (score 2):

Rather than having a build put binaries into source control, you should use NuGet packages and reference your binary dependencies as NuGet packages.

Comment: Yes Daniel that's correct, but now that the source has many projects in it already using the references , it would be tougher to change that and even setting up a NuGet Server to manage the packages

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the **cloaked**  in the source settings-working folders to select the version control paths you want to include and exclude. (Note: suggest you to make sure these filters are consistent with your TFVC workspace mappings.)

For your situation you can cloaked the references folder
[image]

And since you are using the dll in references. The best way just as Daniel suggest using a package management system such as Nuget to host and deploy your  dependencies can eliminate them from source control and allow you avoid the endless loop.

Comment: Cloaking fails my build as i need the references to be copied to the build server . As the solution being built is dependent on the binaries in the References folder. Is there a way where i could update the inbuilt Trigger(In Build Definition) behavior and customize it for my purpose and exclude  the source control folders to not trigger a build ?

Comment: Afraid not, you can't customize the CI trigger in TFS. Moreover, you misunderstood what I meant. Cloaking is the first step, finally you still need to use a package management system such as Nuget to host and deploy your dependencies. It's not recommend to check in dll in TFS source control (`usually use Nuget and GAC`) just in order to avoid such situations(endless loop).